# updated to the latest jade and got error when rendering JavaScript code

Tags: pug

I updated jade today, as:

`npm update jade`

then got a error:

`Unexpected token {`

when rendering something like:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
  $.isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
  if (!$.isSafari) {
  document.write('<style>.safari{display:none}</style>');
  }
```

It was quite good yesterday because I tried it with all the same stuff for a non-updated jade project.

Is there anyone knows how to avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to append a **.** at the end of your script tag as described here :

http://jade-lang.com/reference/#blockinatag

```
script(type='text/javascript').
```